# How to further boost the score given by field_value_factor with ElasticSearch?

Tags: function, boost, elasticsearch, field, pyelasticsearch

I have a question in using the `field_value_factor` with ElasticSearch.

The function that I would like to implement is

```
alpha * log(1 + beta * doc['popularity'].value)
```

When `alpha = 1.0`, the script using the `field_value_factor` is given by

```
"field_value_factor": {
  "field": "popularity",
  "factor": beta,
  "modifier": "log1p"
}
```

as shown in [this link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html):

However, when `alpha != 1.0`, how we can give the weight (i.e. alpha) using the `field_value_factor`?

Do you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 3):

Function score can be cascaded so a combination of [`boost_factor` and field_value_factor](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) 
should allow you to achieve the same.

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "functions": [
            {
               "boost_factor": <alpha>
            },
            {
               "field_value_factor": {
                  "field": "popularity",
                  "factor": <beta>,
                  "modifier": "log1p"
               }
            }
         ],
         "score_mode": "multiply"
      }
   }
}
```